# .ods will open in read-only inside sharepoint online document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

we have a file with.ods extension, but when we try to edit it using the browser, we get this message and the file opens in read-only:-

[image]

is there a way to fox this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenDocument file formats cannot be edited in Office on the web.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so how we can edit this file in this case?

Comment: Open it in the client application (Excel desktop) or convert it to XLSX if you need to edit it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Some features in Excel for the web are **partially supported, not supported** or **not Applicable** in the OpenDocument Spreadsheet format. It will affect formatting ,usability, etc.

Therefore, when we open .ods file in in Excel for the web, some compatibility issues may occur and file shows in read-only mode once we want to edit.

This is the expected behavior and we could click **Edit workbook** to further edit the file.

For more information, please refer to the following article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/differences-between-the-opendocument-spreadsheet-ods-format-and-the-excel-for-windows-xlsx-format-3db958c8-e0ac-49a5-9965-2c2f8afbd960#ID0EAABAAA=Web